# SonarQube Rules squid:S1451 Copyright and license headers should be defined

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

All of my SonarQube code analysis Java projects are failing on this rule.

*Each source file should start with a header stating file ownership and the license which must be used to distribute the application.
This rule must be fed with the header text that is expected at the beginning of every file.*

There is one parameter:

*headerFormat Expected copyright and license header (plain text)*

But there are no examples of how this should be configured. By default headerFormat is empty and I cannot find documentation on configuring this rule.

I'm guessing there should be some kind of regular expression or template language that can be used?

Answer (score 5):

[squid:S1451 "Copyright and license headers should be defined"](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1451) has two parameters:

1. headerFormat
2. isRegularExpression

In **headerFormat** you define expected text. If you set **isRegularExpression** to true, then the text will be treated as regular expression.

If you use normal text, then you need to put full license, e.g.:

```
/*
 * Maven Plugin Utils
 * http://www.gabrys.biz/projects/maven-plugin-utils/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2015 Adam Gabryś
 *
 * This file is licensed under the BSD 3-Clause (the "License").
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at:
 *
 *      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gabrysbiz/maven-plugin-utils/master/src/main/resources/license.txt
 */
```

If you use regular expression, then you can omit some parts, e.g.:

```
^\/\*.+www\.gabrys\.biz\/projects\/.+Copyright \(c\) [0-9]{4}.+This file is licensed under the.+\(the "License"\)\..+You may not use this file except in compliance with the License\..+You may obtain a copy of the License at:.+$
```

Comment: I'm running SonarQube 5.1 and there is only 1 parameter.

Comment: Here's a cut and paste from the rule directly:

Parameters
headerFormat 
Expected copyright and license header (plain text)

Comment: You should upgrade Java Plugin to 3.4 (see http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-656)

Comment: Anyone still here that can tell me where I can set these parameters?

Comment: Open `http://sonar-host/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS1451` → click `Activate` and fill parameters

Answer (score 1):

only change the default text for "headerFormat" on SonarQube server:

[image: quality profile example]

Comment: Sonarqube -> login -> Rules -> Find the rule S1451 -> click on "change" in Qulaiity profile section -> Change the headerFormat.  All rigth.

Comment: note: we fixed the headerFormat to have a "text area" instead of "text field", so for C# the UI is nicer now :)