# How to correctly configure copyright notice regular expression checking on SonarQube?

Tags: regex, sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube Java Plugin 3.7 and trying to set up copyright checking with a regular expression. The rule is called "Copyright and license headers should be defined" with isRegularExpression=true. The reason I'm using a regular expression is just to support different years in the copyright notice, which is the only thing that can change.

I have not been able to get it working so far. Here is my regular expression (with only the company name and job title changed to erase confidential information):

```
^\/\*
 \* Copyright \(c\) [0-9]{4} Acme PLC; All Rights Reserved\.
 \*
 \* This code is confidential to Acme PLC and shall not be disclosed
 \* outside the company without the prior written permission of the Director\.
 \*
 \* In the event that such disclosure is permitted the code shall not be copied
 \* or distributed other than on a need-to-know basis and any recipients may be
 \* required to sign a confidentiality agreement in favour of Acme PLC\.
 \*\/$
```

Here is my copyright notice:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2015 Acme PLC; All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * This code is confidential to Acme PLC and shall not be disclosed
 * outside the company without the prior written permission of the Director.
 *
 * In the event that such disclosure is permitted the code shall not be copied
 * or distributed other than on a need-to-know basis and any recipients may be
 * required to sign a confidentiality agreement in favour of Acme PLC.
 */
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is my **entry** valid (indicating that the actual Sonar configuration itself is wrong)?

Comment: What if you remove the anchors `^` and `$`? Perhaps, there are leading/trailing whitespaces. More, perhaps, there can be double spaces inside the text. Try replacing spaces with `\s*`.

Comment: Thank you @stribizhev, this worked!

Comment: Great I could help. I see you already got a good answer, too. Best of luck with coding! +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is a question of trailing whitespaces at the ends of the lines in the source files.

I regex-ed and tested with a fragment of your copyright and it worked fine for me:

```
/\*
 \* Copyright \(c\) (19|20)[8901][0-9] Acme PLC; All Rights Reserved.
 \*
 \*/
```

Note that I changed the date regex. As written, yours would allow 1436 as the copyright year.

To address trailing whitespaces, I would follow stribizehv's suggestion, `\s*`, for something like this:

```
/\*\s*
 \* Copyright \(c\) (19|20)[8901][0-9] Acme PLC; All Rights Reserved.\s*
 \*\s*
 \*/\s*
```

Of course, my initial tests worked without that because both my regex and my sample copyright message had the same whitespaces.

Comment: Hi, I notice that (a) you didn't escape the "." (dot) character, (b) you didn't escape the "/" (slash) character, (c) you didn't add the anchors (^ and $) at the beginning and end. Are these best practices? Regarding whitespaces at the end of lines, I'm fairly sure it's not that, because I only just autogenerated all my copyrights yesterday (meaning they are identical) and I copy-pasted one of them into Sonar to use as a template for creating the regex. (Incidentally, when I paste it in unmodified, and set isRegularExpression=false, I get no violations of the rule, so that part works.)

Comment: After applying (a-c) above the build still failed, but after adding the `\s*`, it worked! So it must be something to do with that after all. Thanks! And thanks also to @stribizhev

Comment: a) I didn't escape the '.' char mainly for laziness, and because it stands for any single char & therefore a period matches. b) there is no '/' in the sample I worked with. c) I'm dubious about the value of '^' in this type of situation; it implies that you anticipate nested copyright comments...? Essentially, I see it as just a source of future confusion here. Regarding '$' I think it may actually be counter-productive in this situation because the _file_ doesn't end at the end of the copyright notice (or at least I hope it doesn't). But I didn't test that; it's just a guess.

Comment: For (b) I'm not sure what you mean; there is a '/' at the start and end of both of the snippets you posted. For both (b) and (c) I originally tried to follow the practice from this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31463022/191761 where '/' is escaped and it also has the anchors at the start and end. If there is some mistake in that answer, I'm sure I wouldn't be the only one in the community who would benefit from you commenting on that answer as well :)